# Trouble referencing two sql tables

Tags: mysql

For my mySQL database I am trying to display the average of each sectors financial ratios, so I can have a benchmark value per sector.

```
         Companies
```

| companyName | ticker | sector |

```
       profitability
```

| ticker | profitMargin | returnOnAssets |

My query so far is this

```
SELECT c.sector, AVG( p.profitMargin ) , AVG( p.returnOnEquity ) 
FROM Companies c, profitability p
GROUP BY c.sector
```

My output shows each sector and their averages, but the values are the same for each tuple, so its not averaging them correctly. Help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE*
so i tried the left join and it definitely looks better,

[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAv11.png)

I suppose my problem lies elsewhere due to the NULL values. Because the values are not NULL in the actual relation.

Comment: You're currently generating a cartesean product. All records from company are joined to all records in profitability.  How do the tables relate?  Ticker?  if so scaisEdge seems to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join

```
SELECT c.sector, AVG( p.profitMargin ) , AVG( p.returnOnEquity ) 
FROM Companies c
left join  profitability p on c.ticker = p.ticker
GROUP BY c.sector
```

Comment: now only one sector is showing up...could my primary keys be incorrect?

Comment: You should update your question with a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. anyway try with left join  .(some key could not match) .. i have used  ticker  because is the only column in common

Comment: thank you very much! I have updated the results. The ticker is the primary key in both relations

Comment: Your 'only one row is showing up' would indicate that only one sector has a ticker with values in the table.  Check your data.  You could do a join between to select distincts (  select a.ticker, a.sector, b.ticker from (select distinct ticker, sector from companies) as a, (select distinct ticker from profitability) as b where a.ticker = b.ticker;).  If you only get one row, there's your issue.

Comment: Yes  .. you problem is related to the null value in some column .. add the proper value and all rows are foudn with proper value ..